# Fill Eloquent model with extra data from API call

Tags: php, api, eloquent, laravel-7

I have an API that return the detail of my data. the detail data is stored in another server which is why i retrieve the data using API.

```
{
"id": "1234",
"nomor": "123457",
"post": null
}
```

I append the API result data to eloquent model using this configuration

```
class ABR extends Model 
{

protected $appends = ['moredata'];

function getMoredataAttribute() {
    $res = Http::get(link to api);
    $data = json_decode($res->body());
    return $data;
}

}
```

I successfully retrieve and append the extra data from API, but i am not happy with the load time. is there something that can be done to reduce the load time?

Comment: it takes as long as it takes to make a request and get a response

Comment: You may want to look into some kind of cache layer so you're not hitting the API every time you fetch the model. If caching is not an option then there isn't really much you can do.